# How to create a MVC model based on the data that i get from Database from a different assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. I am creating a 3 tier application with 
DataLayer(EF5)
businessLayer(Linq to Entity) and 
Web App(MVC 4)

I create a Data Model(.edmx) and using Entity framework 5 for oracle 11g

I get the required data into a list in my business layer. As show below

```
Public Class Customer_Provider
    Public Function getCustomers() As List(Of Customer)

        Dim list As New List(Of Customer)
        Using db As New Entities
            list = (From u In db.Customer Select u).ToList()
        End Using
        Return list
    End Function
End Class
```

In my web app i add all the references and get the data into the MVC controller using my business layer

```
Function Customer() As ActionResult    
        Dim obj As New Customer_Provider()
        Return View(obj.getCustomers())
    End Function
```

My question is how do i create a model to access this data that i get from obj.GetCustomer() to write the validations and populate the model on to the view. I tried various ways but i unable to do. Could any one please suggest me a method.

MyView page

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MVC_Temp.Customer)
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Customer"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

<h2>Customer</h2>
@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.CustomerID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.CustomerName)
        </td>
<tr>
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using AutoMapper. My Controller

```
        Dim UserList As New List(Of Customer)= val.getvalues()
        Mapper.CreateMap(Of DevLDB.Customer, MVC_temp.Customer)()


       Dim objModel As Customer= Mapper.Map(Of List(of DevLDB.Customer),  List(of  MVC_temp.Customer))(UserList)



        Return View(objModel )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a viewmodel with the properties that you need on your view and there, you can add your necessary validation attributes. If you want to make you life really easy, use AutoMapper to map the viewmodel and model, so you don't need to set the viewmodel properties manually. For example (c#):

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int ID {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then, use your viewmodel as the model for your view. Add the viewmodel classes to your web application project.

*Edit*
Your controller would do something like this:

```
var viewModel = new List<CustomerViewModel>();
var customers = obj.getCustomers();
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
 var customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
 customerViewModel.ID = customer.ID;
 customerViewModel.Name = customer.Name;
 viewModel.Add(customerViewModel);
}

 return View(viewModel);
```

Make sure that your view is set to expect the CustomerViewModel type that you are passing it from your controller.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when i try doing this i am getting a error. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DevLDB.Customer]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVC_Temp.Customer]'.

Comment: Change this line `@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MVC_Temp.Customer)` of your view to `@ModelType IEnumerable(Of DevLDB.Customer)`. This is assuming that DevLDB.Customer is your viewmodel.

Comment: In this case It does not refer to the model in MVC it directly gets the data from the database. Where I can not validate.

Comment: Thanks I have missed the AutoMapper part. it works fine with the Automapper

Comment: Love AutoMapper. :-)  Glad I could help